# How to load a sliding diagonal vector from data stored column-wise with SSE

Tags: c, performance, sse, vectorization, simd

The sliding diagonal vector contains 16 elements, each one an 8-bit unsigned integer.

Without SSE and a bit simplified it would have looked like this in C:

```c
int width=1000000; // a big number
uint8_t matrix[width][16];
fill_matrix_with_interesting_values(&matrix);

for (int i=0; i < width - 16; ++i) {
  uint8_t diagonal_vector[16];
  for (int j=0; j<16; ++j) {
    diagonal_vector[j] = matrix[i+j][j];
  }
  do_something(&diagonal_vector);
}
```

but in my case I can only load column-wise (vertically) from the matrix with the `_mm_load_si128` intrinsics function. The sliding diagonal vector is moving horizontally so I need to load 16 column vectors in advance and use one element from each of those column vectors to create the diagonal vector.

Is it possible to make a fast low-memory implementation for this with SSE?

**Update Nov 14 2016:** Providing some more details. In my case I read single-letter codes from a text file in [FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format). Each letter represents a certain amino acid. Each amino acid has a specific column vector associated with it. That column vector is looked up from a constant table (a [BLOSUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOSUM) matrix). In C code it would look like this

```c
while (uint8_t c = read_next_letter_from_file()) {
   column_vector = lookup_from_const_table(c)
   uint8_t diagonal_vector[16];
   ... rearrange the values from the latest column
       vectors into the diagonal_vector ...

   do_something(&diagonal_vector)
}
```

Comment: Do you have to store the data that way?  Can you instead store it with the diagonals contiguous?  Since one diagonal doesn't overlap with the next, this storage format can still compactly store all the data (with padding at the ends, or something).  To get an arbitrary `matrix[i][j]` element from the diagonal storage, I guess you'd do something like `diags[i-j][j]`.  So you don't need two copies of the data, but you can choose whether diagonal or column-wise access is SIMD-friendly.

Comment: The data is actually not stored that way. I simplified the example too much. The column_vector is looked up from a constant table. I've now updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation I will present only needs one column load per iteration. First we initialize some variables

```c
const __m128i mask1=_mm_set_epi8(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255);
const __m128i mask2=_mm_set_epi8(0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255);
const __m128i mask3=_mm_set_epi8(0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255,0,0,255,255);
const __m128i mask4=_mm_set_epi8(0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255);
__m128i v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15;
```

Then for each step the variable `v_column_load` is loaded with the next column.

```c
v15 = v_column_load;
v7 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v7,v15,mask1);
v3 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v3,v7,mask2);
v1 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v1,v3,mask3);
v0 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v0,v1,mask4);
v_diagonal = v0;
```

In the next step the variable name numbers in `v0`, `v1`, `v3`, `v7`, `v15` are incremented by 1 and adjusted to be in the range 0 to 15. In other words: newnumber = ( oldnumber + 1 ) modulo 16.

```c
v0 = v_column_load;
v8 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v8,v0,mask1);
v4 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v4,v8,mask2);
v2 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v2,v4,mask3);
v1 = _mm_blendv_epi8(v1,v2,mask4);
v_diagonal = v1;
```

After 16 iterations the `v_diagonal` will start to contain the correct diagonal values.

Looking at `mask1`,`mask2`, `mask3`, `mask4`, we see a pattern that can be used to generalize this algorithm for other vector lengths (2^n).

For instance, for vector length 8, we would only need 3 masks and the iteration steps would look like this:

```
v7 = a a a a a a a a
v6 =
v5 =
v4 =
v3 =         a a a a
v2 =
v1 =             a a
v0 =               a

v0 = b b b b b b b b
v7 = a a a a a a a a
v6 =
v5 =
v4 =         b b b b
v3 =         a a a a
v2 =             b b
v1 =             a b

v1 = c c c c c c c c
v0 = b b b b b b b b
v7 = a a a a a a a a
v6 =
v5 =         c c c c
v4 =         b b b b
v3 =         a a c c
v2 =           a b c

v2 = d d d d d d d d
v1 = c c c c c c c c
v0 = b b b b b b b b
v7 = a a a a a a a a
v6 =         d d d d
v5 =         c c c c
v4 =         b b d d
v3 =         a a c d

v3 = e e e e e e e e
v2 = d d d d d d d d
v1 = c c c c c c c c
v0 = b b b b b b b b
v7 = a a a a e e e e
v6 =         d d d d
v5 =     a a c c e e
v4 =       a b b d a

v4 = f f f f f f f f
v3 = e e e e e e e e
v2 = d d d d d d d d
v1 = c c c c c c c c
v0 = b b b b f f f f
v7 = a a a a e e e e
v6 =     b b d d f f
v5 =     a b c d e f

v5 = g g g g g g g g
v4 = f f f f f f f f
v3 = e e e e e e e e
v2 = d d d d d d d d
v1 = c c c c g g g g
v0 = b b b b f f f f
v7 = a a c c e e g g
v6 =   a b c d e f g

v6 = h h h h h h h h
v5 = g g g g g g g g
v4 = f f f f f f f f
v3 = e e e e e e e e
v2 = d d d d h h h h
v1 = c c c c g g g g
v0 = b b d d f f h h
v7 = a b c d e f g h  <-- this vector now contains the diagonal

v7 = i i i i i i i i
v6 = h h h h h h h h
v5 = g g g g g g g g
v4 = f f f f f f f f
v3 = e e e e i i i i
v2 = d d d d h h h h
v1 = c c e e g g i i
v0 = b c d e f g h i  <-- this vector now contains the diagonal

v0 = j j j j j j j j
v7 = i i i i i i i i
v6 = h h h h h h h h
v5 = g g g g g g g g
v4 = f f f f j j j j
v3 = e e e e i i i i
v2 = d d f f h h j j
v1 = c d e f g h i j  <-- this vector now contains the diagonal
```

Sidenote: I discovered this way of loading a diagonal vector when I was working on [an implementation](https://github.com/eriksjolund/diagonalsw)  of the Smith-Waterman algorithm. Some more information can be found on the old SourceForge project [web page](https://sourceforge.net/#rearranging_the_column_vectors_into_diagonal_vectors_sse_version).

Comment: I've always been curious, does anyone try to store sequence data in memory with multiple elements packed into a byte?  An ACGT nucleotide only requires two bits, so you can pack either 4 per byte, or a codon of 3 base pairs into a byte with padding.  Unfortunately there are more than 16 amino-acids, so an AA model can't pack more than one into a byte without  insane bit-string crap.  You could pack three 5-bit AAs into 16 bits, but that's probably not worth the overhead for random-access.

Comment: (I used to work with the phylogenetics group at Dalhousie, mostly on finding maximum-likelihood trees for evolutionary models, so the real work each iteration was on matrices of floats; evolutionary distances were just inputs.  e.g. software like phyml, IIRC, not on finding matches in giant sequence databases.)

Comment: Since your masks are compile-time constants, your code would run faster if you used constant blends when possible (i.e. for the steps where granularity >= 16 bits).  PBLENDW runs faster than PBLENDVB (see http://agner.org/optimize).  The first step could maybe also be done with MOVHPS or something, to merge a new upper half of a vector.

Comment: If you need multiple consecutive diagonals, isn't there some redundancy you can take advantage of here, maybe with PALIGNR and PSHUFB?  It seems like you're doing 16 * 4 PBLENDVB operations for every 16 diagonal vectors you produce.

Comment: I would imagine that PUNPCKLBW to interleave bytes from (the low half of) two vectors might be useful, but it still requires one shuffle-port uop to combine a pair of registers, and may not lead to any fewer than 4 ops per result vector.  Hmm.  If you have AVX2, VPBLENDD can do immediate blends (with 32b granularity) with better throughput than PBLENDW on Intel Haswell, but it's still the same operation.

Comment: A lot of ideas. It will take some time too look into all these ideas. The [current implementation] (https://github.com/eriksjolund/diagonalsw/blob/2457c78d233bdd991f7273fb067a0bf10dd8eaa9/src/c/smith_waterman_sse_byte.2load_HFsave8th.xml) generated out with XSLT. Sorry about that. The source code should be converted into a C/C++ only solution without any help from XML/XSLT.

Comment: "Does anyone try to store sequence data in memory with multiple elements packed into a byte?" Interesting question. I don't know but I could ask some colleagues at work.

Comment: Yeah, I had a lot of ideas, but I'm not yet sure if any of them are useful.  None of the final bytes in on 16B diagonal vector overlaps at all with any of the bytes in the previous one.  Maybe we can take advantage of some stages of blending by moving data horizontally within a vector, either with an unpack or with a `_mm_bslli` (PSLLDQ) or PALIGNR on the mask2 or mask3 result for example, not on the final mask4 result?  I haven't really given this a serious look yet, but I'll do so if it could actually speed up real open-source code.

Comment: After looking at this for a while, I think log2(vectorsize) blends per diagonal result is probably optimal.  You need one blend per result in the last depth layer, from two inputs that are each reused twice in the layer above that, etc.  I didn't look carefully at your algorithm the first time, and missed the fact that you are getting lots of reuse.  Without any reuse, it would take 15 blends per diagonal result vector.

Comment: With the right choice of blend instructions, it's probably optimal (VPBLENDD or BLENDPS for 32b granularity or higher, PBLENDW for 16b, and PBLENDVB only for 8b).  BLENDPS has extra bypass-delay latency, but can run on more ports than PBLENDW.  I think there's enough going on in parallel that latency doesn't matter.  But similarly, looking at the asm output, the blends are mixed with enough other stuff that shuffle-port pressure probably isn't a big deal either, and PBLENDW for all the blends would be fine for the non-AVX2 case.  Then the byte-granularity PBLENDVB mask can stay in xmm0.

Comment: When the number of elements is >= the number of vector registers (e.g. 16 byte elements), this probably spills to memory so the efficiency of this pattern of N variables as a rotating history buffer breaks down.  Doing the byte and word blends first so you end up with something like `[ a3 b4 c5 d6 | e3 f4 g5 h6 ]` could be useful, so you can store the low half of the vector to memory for later loading (using `MOVLPS` or something, which runs on Intel SnB-family CPUs as one micro-fused load+shuffle uop).

Comment: I didn't come up with any use for horizontal data movement, since column vectors already have their elements in the right place.  I don't see how to enable use of 1 uop PUNPCKLBW / PUNPCKHBW instead of multi-uop PBLENDVB.  We can store the data in column vectors in a different order, to match the way we want to shuffle it, but unless we have 2 copies of the BLOSUM matrix in different orders (`[odds | evens]` maybe?) , I don't think that can work.  Of course that's possible, if the extra cache footprint is not too big.  Loads from cache are cheap.  (I should turn these comments into an answer)

Comment: I'll write more but just a short comment first: Yes log2(vectorsize) is what is needed when we have enough vector registers. But when you have too few vector register, instead of storing half of the vector for later reuse as you suggest, isn't it better to reuse each amino acid letter two times? So before all the "log2"-blending you would load the lower half of the initial vector from letter c1 and the upper half from letter c2. The two letters c1 and c2 are located N/2 bytes apart in the FASTA input file. N is here the SIMD vector length.

Comment: Yeah, that's the other approach: do the first step of blending with MOVHPS or MOVLPS to get vectors like `[ a0..h0 | i8..p8 ]`.  Hmm, yeah that's probably better, since it's the same amount of loads, but without any stores.  (And instead of `MOVHPS`, you can actually use `VPBLENDD`/`BLENDPS`/`PBLENDW` with a memory operand, since your BLOSUM column vectors are aligned.  But they don't micro-fuse a memory operand so they're 2 fused-domain uops, while MOVHPS is one.  PINSRQ is another option, but it's less efficient than MOVHPS on modern Intel.)

Comment: I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/eriksjolund/diagonalsw/issues/4) regarding the blend instructions. I replaced some  _mm_blendv_epi8 with _mm_blend_epi16
and _mm_blend_epi3  https://github.com/eriksjolund/diagonalsw/commit/4f2b2c8d66d595c74806e43e306541f53742ecdf It gave 29% speedup but I think I changed a bit too many things at the same time so take that number with a grain of salt.

Comment: The code in that commit looks sensible.  I didn't end up coming up with any obvious improvements other than using immediate blends, and `_mm_blend_epi32` is extremely efficient.  (Can run on all three vector ALU ports, so it's even better than MOVHPS when it's available, for this use-case).  When AVX2 is not available, you'll probably get good results from just using `_mm_blend_epi16` for the first three blends.  There is other stuff you could do, but it's probably a lot of trouble for a small chance of gaining anything (e.g. cast to float to use BLENDPD / BLENDPS).